# Multithreading issue for two separate sources

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, opencv

I am trying to run two functions at the same time. One function is supposed to detect scenes from local video and the other should detect scenes from my webcam. Then I make some processing with these scenes. Here is the code snippet:

```
scenes_1 = []
scenes_2 = []

scene_manager1 = SceneManager()
scene_manager1.add_detector(ContentDetector(threshold=30.0))

scene_manager2 = SceneManager()
scene_manager2.add_detector(ContentDetector(threshold=30.0))

def callback_1(image, frame_num):
  global scenes_1
  print("callback_1: Found a scene on video 1.")
  scenes_1 += [(image, frame_num)]

def callback_2(image, frame_num):
  global scenes_2
  print("callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.")
  scenes_2 += [(image, frame_num)]

def function_1():
    video_capture_0 = BrowserVideoCapture(src=0)

    while True:
        ret0,frame0=video_capture_0.read()
        if(ret0):
            scene_manager1.detect_scenes(frame0, callback=callback_1)
        else:
            break
    video_capture_0.release()

def function_2():

    video_capture_1 = cv2.VideoCapture("Our Story.mp4")

    while True:
        ret1,frame1=video_capture_1.read()
        if(ret1):
            scene_manager2.detect_scenes(frame1, callback=callback_2)
            if cv2.waitKey(34) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        else:
            break
    video_capture_1.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

t1=threading.Thread(target=function_1)
t2=threading.Thread(target=function_2)

t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()

while True:
  for im, frame_num in scenes_2:
    tar_image_example = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    tar_image_example = tar_image_example.astype(np.uint8)
    print("Found scene at frame %d in video 2." % frame_num)
    tar_image_example += 1
  for im, frame_num in scenes_1:
    src_image_example = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    src_image_example = src_image_example.astype(np.uint8)
    print("Found scene at frame %d in video 1." % frame_num)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-29:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-25-1d65acb7c14c>", line 71, in function_2
    scene_manager2.detect_scenes(frame1, callback=callback_2)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scenedetect/scene_manager.py", line 626, in detect_scenes
    timecode=0, fps=frame_source.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get'

Exception in thread Thread-28:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-25-1d65acb7c14c>", line 54, in function_1
    scene_manager1.detect_scenes(frame0, callback=callback_1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scenedetect/scene_manager.py", line 626, in detect_scenes
    timecode=0, fps=frame_source.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-1d65acb7c14c> in <module>()
    112     tar_image_example = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    113     tar_image_example = tar_image_example.astype(np.uint8)
--> 114     print("Found scene at frame %d in video 2." % frame_num)
    115   for im, frame_num in scenes_1:

KeyboardInterrupt:
```

The code continuously switches between for loops without any output...
What am I doing wrong, please?

Comment: put the joins behind the loops in the main. Currently it shouldnt enter the while loop because it will wait on the join until the threads have finished, which wont happen unless capturing fails.

Comment: Unfortunately, the issue persists, even without joins.